# System Settings isn't opening

Tags: unity, 14.04, system-settings

I can click on system settings, however nothing occurs.

My output when trying to open it in terminal:

```
unity-control-center
libpulsecommon-4.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libsound.so
libGL error: Couldn't dlopen libudev.so.1 or libudev.so.0, driver detection may be broken.
unity-control-center: ../../../../src/loader/loader.c:129: asserted_dlsym: Assertion `result' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: This question wasnt about the dev version of ubuntu. It was on the newest LTS (Tahr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to be one package is missing that required to open system settings.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpulse0
```

The above command will reinstall the package and get if anything missing.

install it and restart your PC and try again.

Comment: this does not work for me